# Can't display sign '-' with rails enumerize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, enumerize

I am using enumerize in my rails app. In model/user :

```
enumerize :ranking, in: ['- 2/6', '- 4/6', '- 15', '- 30']
```

in my views I have user/edit.html.erb I have

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user)  do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :ranking, label: "Classement" %>
```

...

The problem is only in the option list on select : when the option is actually selected and the form submitted. It displays nicely the minus sign in user/show
The generated html for the select is as follows

```
<option value="- 2/6"> 2/6</option>
<option value="- 4/6"> 4/6</option>
<option value="- 15"> 15</option>
```

so the value is right but not the text inside the tags

It displays the select options but the "-" sign that precedes all ranking  doesnt display. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't in the view.  What is the value of `@user.ranking?`

Comment: actually the problem is only in the option list on select : when the option is actually selected. It displays nicely the minus sign in user/show

Comment: What's the generated html, for the select tag?

Comment: `
<option value="- 2/6"> 2/6</option>
<option value="- 4/6"> 4/6</option>
<option value="- 15"> 15</option>
`
@MaxWilliams

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own problem. If you go check the gem running

```
bundle show enumerize
```

in your console. You will find in scope / value.rb file :

```
def i18n_keys
 i18n_keys << self.underscore.humanize # humanize value if there are no translations
end
```

When the translation of the given value is not defined in the I18N file, enumerize runs the methods underscore and humanize on the string.
So I actually solved the problem by updating my I18n file with all my `rankings` values.